# accessing specific textblock from a listbox on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, data-binding, textblock

I have an xml file downloaded and saved to the phone first and then opened when user navigates to certain pages in the app. Now I already know how to view all the contents I want to show using a listbox and some textblocks bindings.

XML is like:

```
  <root>
    <ratings>
      <rating>
        <ratings/>
        <businessID/>
        <counters/>
      </rating>
     ...
    </ratings>
  </root>
```

XAML

```
   <ListBox x:Name="sI" 
                 Foreground="Sienna" Margin="368,283,61,-144" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textblock1" Text="{Binding counter} FontSize="30"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I want to access the textblock that is inside the listbox, it is giving me up to 5 different values, and add them to specific ProgressBars. The page will be displaying up 5 Textblocks and 5 progressbars that will be getting the value of the Textblocks. I have searched a lot and tried a lot of things but I'm getting various errors and messages instead of what I want regarding accessing the textblock.

This is how I load the file.

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new
                    XmlSerializer(typeof(Ratings));
                    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                    Ratings ratings = (Ratings)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
```

This is how I can view the items at a listbox with some added arguments

```
 sI.ItemsSource = ratings.Collection.Where(c => c.businessID == businessID).ToList();
```

And I want to do something like this.

```
 textblock1.DataContext/Text = ratings.Collection.Where(c => c.businessID == businessID && c.ratings == "4").ToString();
```

The above gives me this message in the Textblock instead:

```
 System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Name_of_the_solution.Rating]
```

and something like this to get the textblock1 value and place it on the progressbar

```
 progressbar4.Value = Double.Parse(textblock1.Text);
```

I tried those unsuccessfully as well.

```
  var elem = from element in document.Elements("ratings")
                              where (string)element.Attribute("rating") == "2" &&
                              (string)element.Attribute("businessID") == businessID
                              select elements().Element("counter");

 var filteredData = from c in document.Descendants("Rating")
                                      where c.Attribute("rating").Value == "1" && c.Attribute("businessID").Value == businessID.ToString()
                                     select new Rating()
                                      {
                                          counter = c.Attribute("counter").Value
                                      };
```

giving me almost the same message :

```
 System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`2[Name_of_the_solution.Rating]
```

I have thought as well to bypass all this, not recommended but I'm desperate at this point, to make 5 Listboxes with 1 Textblock each, but I still can't get the value out of them to place each one on the progressbar that I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't use `bind` directly on XAML, loading information from your collection?

Comment: @ReneSá Binding directly on XAML like this
    <TextBlock x:Name="ficounter" Text="{Binding counter}"/>
 gives me null. And if it were to give me something, what would that be ? How would it know where and when to put each value. As I said there are 5 Textblocks to fill 5 counters, but the counters to be filled are 75 at this moment. That's why I wrote Where(c => c.businessID == businessID && c.ratings == "5").ToString();

Comment: Have you tried with List<Ratings> ratings = (List<Ratings>)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());. I think you are having multiple rating under ratings tag. And then use simple linq query.

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia Hi, I made my problem more specific so you can understand better what I want to do.

Comment: I have tried with given XML but XML is wrong. why have you taken <ratings> two times? Can you please paste actual XML?

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia XML has a node called ratings and inside it has many rating. It is not wrong that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am always trying to do something in programming with the wrong and difficult approach when the answer was as simple as that.

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new
                    XmlSerializer(typeof(Ratings));
                    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                    Ratings ratings = (Ratings)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());

                    var result = ratings.Collection.Where(c => c.businessID == businessID);
                    if (result == null) return;
                    double db = 0.0;

                    ficounter.Text = result.Where(c => c.ratings == 5).Select(c => c.counter).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (double.TryParse(ficounter.Text, out db))
                        fiprogress.Value = db;

                    focounter.Text = result.Where(c => c.ratings == 4).Select(c => c.counter).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (double.TryParse(focounter.Text, out db))
                        foprogress.Value = db;

                    thcounter.Text = result.Where(c => c.ratings == 3).Select(c => c.counter).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (double.TryParse(thcounter.Text, out db))
                        thprogress.Value = db;

                    twcounter.Text = result.Where(c => c.ratings == 2).Select(c => c.counter).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (double.TryParse(twcounter.Text, out db))
                        twprogress.Value = db;

                    oncounter.Text = result.Where(c => c.ratings == 1).Select(c => c.counter).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (double.TryParse(oncounter.Text, out db))
                        onprogress.Value = db;
```

That way I just pass the value into a var and then with a query I put the value to a Textblock and that value to a progress bar.